Reset a branch and its remote to master
The problem I'm trying to solve:

Need to reset a (testing) branch to the head of master once per day.
Need this so when people pull, they end up in the same state.

What I've tried:

git reset --hard master
git push --force

The problem with what I've tried:

When people pull the branch, git then helpfully merges any commits they had on their checkout onto the incoming branch, which is usually everything that was on the branch before the force push. It needs to be reset on a pull.

Background:
The branch is used for testing in an environment where git flow sadly isn't an option. So we merge changes pre-review on to a testing branch each day, run tests on that (which takes 12 hours) overnight and reset it to master the following day to do the whole thing again with new changes/feedback from tests etc.
Question:
How do we do this in a way that's reliable and requires the minimal amount of work for developers possible? (note, the process is fixed. It's clearly not ideal, but is the best option so I'm not looking for comments on that in this post).

git reset --hard master and git push --force do not do merges. Where does your claim "Git then helpfully merges their local changes" come from?

Thanks! I can see that I'd missed a sentence out there. Super helpful.

Every developer (who pulls) needs to configure to overwrite their local branch with the one that is pulled in. Alternatively (and more easy): don’t bother checking out a branch. Check out the remote-tracking branch directly.

Git's standard workflows aren't really meant to rewrite history. Normally you should not rewrite history for branches which have been published to a remote, which other colleagues may be working on. (And git reset rewrites history)
If you want to do this, rather than using a single branch which gets reset every week, consider using a different branch name for the test branch each week. E.g. testbranch_2024.40 for branch for 2024, week 40, and then create a new branch next week testbranch_2024.41.
This more clearly indicates that these are independent branches with different commit histories. This is the approach we use for creating release branches (which in a way are test branches where additional release testing is run before making a release).
If you necessarily want to keep the branch, you simply shouldn't use use git pull to fetch the changes. git pull means "fetch the latest updates from remote, and merge them into my local branch". If you want to discard you local history, and force-update your local branch you should instead do something like:
git fetch origin +testbranch:testbranch
testbranch:testbranch is called a refspec (see git fetch man pages). It essentially means "fetch the testbranch from the remote repository and use it to update my local testbranch. The + means allow a force-update (ie a non-fast-forward update (necessary since you are leaving the the commits from last weeks state behind)).

Having the same branch and rewriting it is fine if it’s an integration branch or something like that. You’re probably gonna document that anyway.

Helpful -- am I doing something wrong though as when I run that command (with the appropriate branch name of course) I get ssh: Could not resolve hostname +<test_branch_name>: Name or service not known

@DavidBoshton you gave the branch name for the host name. That should be the server name or something.

@Guildenstern Unsure what you mean. Can you expand that for me? Currently trying to get my head around the git fetch docs without success...

@DavidBoshton Sorry. I meant that this answer should probably be changed to git fetch origin +testbranch:testbranch.  The syntax is git fetch <remote> <refspec>. Right, Alderath? Can you edit that?

Sorry. My bad. Yes, I was sloppy and forgot the remote in the command. Updated the answer.

"If you necessarily want to keep the branch, you simply shouldn't use use git pull to fetch the changes." I would argue that using git pull is more often a mistake than not. At the very least, use of git pull --rebase is preferable. If you use interactive rebase, you can then select which of the local commits (if any) you want to keep. Be aware that there is a learning curve associated with that, but I'm confident that your developers can learn these things.
